# How could I remove repetition from this linq-to-entities query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This linq query works, and it does what I want it to do, but is there any other way I could improve the query so I'm not repeating `a.AnswerRevisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()`?

```
IQueryable<Article> query = from a in _db.Articles
                            orderby a.DateCreated descending
                            where a.AnswerRevisions.Count > 0 &&
                            (a.AnswerRevisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault().UpVotes -
                             a.AnswerRevisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault().DownVotes < 0)
                            select a;
```

Comment: I'd rather do `.UpVotes < .Downvotes`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `let` statement and also do the final `orderby` after the `where` clause, this will increase efficiency, as less entries will have to be sorted

```
IQueryable<Article> query = from a in _db.Articles 
    let  rev = a.AnswerRevisions.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()
    where a.AnswerRevisions.Count > 0 && 
          (rev.UpVotes - rev.DownVotes < 0) 
    orderby a.DateCreated descending 
    select a;
```

Comment: Ok thanks that's great - never used the let clause before, works really well in this situation. Kudos on the orderby too, I was under the impression that with linq-to-entities the orderby had to be before the where but I was wrong on that front!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query generated by EF will account for the order of ordering/filtering, and if not, the underlying DB should when executing the query. I haven't actually tested it though, so don't quote me on that!

Comment: It might make no difference with EF, but if you have linq-to-objects it will. In SQL the `order by` comes always after `where`. It feels better to have  order by at the end.